# How does a gsl_vector own a gsl_block?

Tags: gsl

In the reference manual of GSL it is written that

> The pointer block stores the location of the memory block in which the vector elements are located (if any). If the vector owns this block then the owner field is set to one and the block will be deallocated when the vector is freed.

But what does it mean 'If the vector owns the block'?

The following is the structure of gsl_vector

```
typedef struct
{
  size_t size;
  size_t stride;
  double * data;
  gsl_block * block;
  int owner;
} gsl_vector;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> For consistency all memory is allocated through a gsl_block structure.

Next:

> Vectors and matrices are made by slicing an underlying block.

Basically, you can use an existing block of memory to get a new vector using, for example, (for some reason undocumented) functions `alloc_from_block` or `alloc_from_vector`. In such cases `owner` is set to 0 and when you free a vector that initial block stays allocated:

```
void
FUNCTION (gsl_vector, free) (TYPE (gsl_vector) * v)
{
  RETURN_IF_NULL (v);

  if (v->owner)
    {
      FUNCTION(gsl_block, free) (v->block) ;
    }
  free (v);
}
```

Comment: @Nownuri No problem, I'm not a full-time C programmer, however, I do use GSL in my research so I tried to make it as simple and correct as possible.